# Branch names not matching using QtCreator and Git (GitHub)

Tags: git, github, version-control, qt-creator

I have embarked on moving my project into the git environment for version control, moving from a manual system of change logging.

I have set up a GitHub account, cloned the repository to my local machine and got things working. I have set up my local and remote branches like this image taken from my QtCreator IDE:

[image: local and remote branches]

I have set my development branch in GitHub as my default branch, and here are my branches on GitHub:
[image: github branches]

I have made several successful commits, and have used the push command by right clicking on the 'development' branch and selecting push as shown:

[image: push from development branch to development branch]

The problem is that when I type the command git push, I get this warning:

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push . HEAD:main

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push . HEAD

To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help config'.

To avoid automatically configuring an upstream branch when its name
won't match the local branch, see option 'simple' of branch.autoSetupMerge
in 'git help config'.
```

I am not quite sure what this is telling me. Could someone help assist and guide me to a resolution? I have read about the definitions of 'origin' 'main' 'head' but they haven't made things clearer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue - it's a regression bug in QtCreator. Please report at https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa